# JMeter looping with indexes and property update

Tags: loops, properties, jmeter, load-testing

I'm attempting to create a test plan when a certain value is reached, then some functionality happens. The test plan consists of multiple threads running with a loop, and when some condition is reached I'd like to fire an HTTP request .

I'll drill down to the guts of it:
In my test I have logic in a looping way with multiple threads, and when a condition is met (the condition is met every 10 seconds) then I need to iterate through a value that it's value should be saved from the previous iteration - that value which I defined is a property (inside `user.properties`) - `startIndex = 0` (initialized to 0).
So I've made a `While Controller` which it's condition is like this:

`${__javaScript(${__P(startIndex,)}<=${currBulk},)}`

And I expect the HTTP request, which depends on `startIndex` value inside the while to be executed when `startIndex<=currBulk` variable.

Inside the `While Controller` the HTTP request should to be fired until all indexes are covered, and I've written it like this inside `BeanShell PostProcessor`:

```
int startIndexIncInt = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("startIndex")); //get the initiated index of the loop
startIndexIncInt = startIndexIncInt + 1; //increment it and see if needed to fire the request again, by the original While condition
vars.put("startIndexIncIntVar", String.valueOf(startIndexIncInt));
props.put("startIndex",vars.get("startIndexIncIntVar")); //the property incremental and update
```

So, I designed it like in order that in the next time (after 10 more seconds) I'll have an updated `startIndex` that will be compared to the new `currBulk` (which is always updated by my test plan).
And I just cant have it done . I keep receiving errors like:

```
 startIndexIncInt = Integer.parseInt(props.ge . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Integer.parseInt
```

Needless to say that also the `var startIndexIncIntVar` I defined isn't setted (I checked via debug sampler).
Also, my problem isn't with the time entering the while, my problems are basically with the variable that I should increment and use inside my HTTP request (the while condition, and beanshell post processor script)

Just for more info on it, if I'd written it as pseudo code it would look like this:

```
startInc = 0
----Test plan loop----
------ test logic, currBulk incremented through the test-----
if(time condition to enter while){
  while (startIndex <= currBulk){
  Send HTTP request (the request depends on startIndex value)
  startIndex++
  } 
}
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a problem with your `startIndex` property as I fail to see any Beanshell script error, the code is good so my expectation is that `startIndex` property is unset or cannot be cast to the integer. You can get a way more information regarding the problem in your Beanshell script in 2 ways:

1. Add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of your script - you will see a lot of debugging output in the console window.
2. Put your code inside [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       int startIndexIncInt = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("startIndex")); //get the initiated index of the loop
       startIndexIncInt = startIndexIncInt + 1; //increment it and see if needed to fire the request again, by the original While condition
       vars.put("startIndexIncIntVar", String.valueOf(startIndexIncInt));
       props.put("startIndex", vars.get("startIndexIncIntVar")); //the property incremental and update
   } catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Beanshell script failure", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   this way you will be able to see the cause of the problem in *jmeter.log* file

Actually it appears that you are overscripting as incrementing a variable can be done using built-in components like [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element or [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function. See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article for more information on the domain.